# How do I set the language mode for Rubinius?

Tags: ruby, rubinius

I'm trying to set the language mode in Rubinius, and it doesn't seem to work. I tried using the switch suggested by the Rubinius team in April 2012 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165964/38765

```
$ ruby --version
rubinius 2.0.0.n203 (1.9.3 4d75a146 2013-07-22 JI) [x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2]
$ ruby -X18
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
irb(main):002:0> exit
$ ruby -X20
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
```

Is it possible to set language mode any more for Rubinius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the language modes when compiling rubinius. From the [docs](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius):

> For example, to enable both 1.9 and 2.0 modes, with 1.9 the default,
>   use the follwing configure options:
>
> ```
> ./configure --enable-version=1.9,2.0 --default-version=1.9
> ```

Comment: It seem no longer true for Rubinus 2.3.0... Is there any other way?